# How to change the serving url for a reactjs app?

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

What I want is to serve my react app from a path inside the server root (e.g. localhost:3000/path). **I don't want to manage this with app routing**, so please do not suggest it. My app is to ben unaware about that.

Is there a way to obtain this?

Comment: How do you start your app, via `create-react-app`, `vite` or `webpack`?

Comment: create-react-app